# Return in Robot Framework

Tags: robotframework

I am trying to return a value from a keyword to my test case, but I am getting error

Variable 'xxx' not found.

This is my code.

```html
*** Keywords ***
Click Dispatched check box from Status
    ${dispatchOptionPresent}=  run keyword and return status  click element  ${selectDispatchedCheckbox_xpath}
    set global variable  ${g_dispatchOptionPresent}  ${dispatchOptionPresent}
    run keyword if  '${dispatchOptionPresent}' == 'False'  NoDispatchedStatusFoundforSelection
    ...  ELSE  Set Test Message  *HTML* Applied <b>'Dispatched'</b> status filter
    click element  xpath://body
    sleep   2

NoDispatchedStatusFoundforSelection
    Fail  'Dispatched' status option not found...
    [Return]  ${g_dispatchOptionPresent}

*** Test Cases ***

Click 'Dispatched' check box for Status
    [Tags]  Filter-From Date/Status for LOA
    [Documentation]  Test to select 'Dispatched' check box for Status
    ${dispatchStatusFound}=     Click Dispatched check box from Status
    set global variable  ${g_dispatchStatusFound}   ${dispatchStatusFound}
    pass execution if  '${g_dispatchStatusFound}' == 'False'  *HTML* <b>'Dispatch'</b> status found for selection!!!
```

For some reason, the test case is not seeing the returned value from the keyword section.
I checked for any formatting issues also, but no luck.

A similar scenario in one of my another test case works correctly with [Return]

But this one throws me :

> Variable '${g_dispatchStatusFound}' not found.

Any help is much appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: `Click Dispatched check box from Status` does not have return value.

Comment: If the variable is global, why do you think you need to return it?

Comment: Thank you for your help. The return statement is present in "NoDispatchedStatusFoundforSelection" KW. run keyword if  '${dispatchOptionPresent}' == 'False' is executed which calls NoDispatchedStatusFoundforSelection" KW and the return is not passed on to the test case.

Comment: @user13906858 even so, when `NoDispatchedStatusFoundforSelection` is ran in that `if` inside `Click Dispatched check box from Status`, its returned value is not assigned to any variable, and not propagated outside by the enclosing keyword. In effect, `dispatchStatusFound` in the test case would get a value `${None}`. Can you describe in short what you're trying to achieve, what's your end goal?

Comment: @user13906858 If any answer works for you accept it. It is one of the way to appreciate community members and to direct other users to the right or working answer of the question. I could see out of 8 post none of the answers are accepted. This could lead your future post unanswered or with less response. If answer is not working for you state it or ask for clarification in comments section.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I am yet to try my previous posts to check if they are working, that's the reason for delay. Sorry for that.

Comment: Coming back to this issue, what I am trying to achieve here is: My TC calls "Click Dispatched check box from Status" KW where I am checking for a 'Dispatch' check box is available as one of the option for status. If not present, call "NoDispatchedStatusFoundforSelection" KW and return a 'False' to the TC. Based on the click element response, I am storing the True/False value in a global variable and returning the global variable to the TC. I wasn't  sure I could reference the global variable set in a robot file from a different robot file and that's the reason I was using [Return] statement.